# Android xml scene + programatically way

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, facade

How to combine the Android xml scene with programatically way?

Combine both to reuse the content from xml but create different variants.

example:

```kotlin
val variant = getVariant()
val example_1 = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.example_1, variant)
```